# Автоудаление сообщений в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть ли у aiogram возможность автоудаление сообщения... Я пробую так реализовать но у меня ошибка TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation. Все чтобы я не вставлял ниже await message.anwer не хочет работать.. отступы вроде норм.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands='weather')
async def command_weather(message: types.Message):
    global last_time
    if (datetime.datetime.now() - last_time).seconds < 600:
        await message.answer("Хтось вже користувався цією командою. Запустити ще раз можна буде через 10хв.")
        time.sleep(5)
        await message.delete()
        return
    
    await message.answer(weather.get_weather())
    last_time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: Не, отступы не норм. Пожалуйста, приведите полную ошибку в вопрос, нажав кнопку [edit]

Comment: Как мне удалить сообщение которое отправилось await message.answer так как await message.delete() удаляет сообщение /weather

Answer (score 0):

Просто запиши это в переменную и её и удаляй.

```
import asyncio
@dp.message_handler(commands='weather')
async def command_weather(message: types.Message):
    global last_time
    if (datetime.datetime.now() - last_time).seconds < 600:
        delete_msg = await message.answer("Хтось вже користувався цією командою. Запустити ще раз можна буде через 10хв.")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await delete_msg.delete()
        return
    
    await message.answer(weather.get_weather())
    last_time = datetime.datetime.now()
```